# After install of kubuntu-full, no longer have access to Unity login

Tags: unity, kubuntu, login

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 about a week ago. Just today I went ahead and installed kubuntu-full to get KDE and it's associated programs. I want to keep the Unity login screen though (default when you install Ubuntu). I can't seem to get this working. Doing a 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm' or 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm' and choosing either one of those does not get me there.

If I choose gdm, I just end up with a gnome login screen. If I pick lightdm, I end up with a KDE login screen. Doesn't seem to be an option for choosing the unity login screen (whatever it's called).

Any assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `unity-greeter` if it is missing.

and edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` change `greeter-session=lightdm-kde-greeter` to `greeter-session=unity-greeter` and probably restart lightdm with `sudo service lightdm restart` or reboot

Comment: Would the person that did the down vote please explain themselves? It's not like this is a bad answer in the sense of that it's harming the installation. Besides, this is a new user, if new users do something wrong, explain them how they could do better!

Comment: My bet was on an `update-alternatives` solution, but after installing the `kubuntu-full` package, I couldn't find a corresponding alternative, neither `ldm-theme` nor `x-session-manager` are correct, only the above solution works. But my greeter was still Unity after KDE installation.

Comment: This method worked halfway for me.  It brought back the Unity log-in screen only after I log-out from the first session.  On my actual startup, I'm still getting the Kubuntu black screen, and no log-in screen at all.